# Not able to register spring boot service with eureka on external tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy two spring boot application services on external tomcat.

1. Eureka service
2. Client service

When I deployed these two services on external tomcat, I am able to deploy and I am able to access these two services separately but my client service is not able register with Eureka service and I can't see it on eureka console.

My Eureka service properties file:

```
#EureakaService.properties#
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
spring.application.name=EurekaServiceApplication
logging.level.com.netflix.eureka=OFF
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=OFF
```

Below is my Client service properties file

```
#ClientService.properties#
spring.application.name=CBEApplication
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8080/eureka-server-1.8.0
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my configuration settings.

Comment: show client side properties and main class annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient

Comment: Turn on DEBUG log, that's why it exists, to help debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

## EurekaService class as below#                                                                                                               @EnableEurekaServer

@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServiceApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(EurekaServiceApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
}                                                                                                                               #Client Class code as below#                                                                          @SpringBootApplication
```

@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CBEApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(CBEApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(CBEApplication.class, args);

}
```

}